# Strange configuration for last layer

Tags: rubiks-cube

I am trying to solve my Rubik's cube but last layer has got strange configuration which I am not able to solve. I'm following algorithm shown on [this](https://www.wired.com/story/how-to-solve-a-rubiks-cube-step-by-step/) page.

Here is the layout:[image]

As you can see green pieces are both on opposite of each other.

Comment: That article is pretty bad. I would recommend Googling 2-look PLL to finish the step you're currently at. There's plenty of YouTube videos that will help you a lot more, such as the one by JPerm.

Comment: Yup, `R U R' U' R' F R2 U' R' U' R U R' F'` resolved [jprem](https://jperm.net/algs/2lookpll). It is called headlights same color on opposite corners.

Answer (score 0):

This is a GB perm, in order to solve it, let the blue side(Headlights) be on your left and do this algorithm:D ( R' U' R U ) D' ( R2 U R' U ) ( R U' R U' ) R2'. If you don't know notation, ' just means counterclockwise, so R' is the right layer turned down, or in the counterclockwise direction. And the D is the bottom layer.